# how to insert parent table all ids into child table using foreign key reference in sql server? Update all foreign key values?

Tags: sql, sql-server

[image]

How to insert parent table primary keys ids into Child table using foreign key references in sql server?

Comment: _How to insert parent table primary keys ids into Child table using foreign key references?_ What do you mean by that? your question is not clear, please **[edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/52040212/edit)** your question.

Comment: I can only assume you want to update your child table values? There is nothing in the data you posted that will make this possible. The challenge is that your question is just too vague. This might be a good place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: where did child table referred  the parent table columns..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> As your question is not clear, this answer still can be edited according to the information you provide.

The only thing I can imagine you are trying to do is:

```
UPDATE Child
SET ParentID = CASE WHEN ChildID IN (1, 2) THEN 1 ELSE 2 END;

SELECT *
FROM Child;
```

Which will return:

```
+---------+-----------+----------+
| ChildID | ChildName | ParentID |
+---------+-----------+----------+
|       1 | CollPad   |        1 |
|       2 | MicroMax  |        1 |
|       3 | Dell      |        2 |
|       4 | Mac       |        2 |
+---------+-----------+----------+
```

If this is not the case, please edit your question to include more information and description to the issue you are trying to acheive.